# Let R be a Boolean ring with unity. Show that $0$ is the only nilpotent element and $1$ is the only unit.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

A ring is said to be Boolean if $x^2=x$ for all $x \in R$ .

I tried it this way: let $x \neq 0$ ,
$x^n=0$ and

$x^2=x$ so $x^{2n}=x^{n}=(-x)^n$ How do I show that $x=0$?

For unit part:
Let x be a unit so there exits $y \neq 0$ and and $xy=1$ then $xy=yx$ as we know that the Boolean ring is commutative and then $(xy)^2=xy=1$ and we have $x^2=x$ and $y^2=y$ so $(xy)^2=xy=x^2y^2$ then??

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, $x^2=x$ implies that $x^3=x^2x=x^2=x$ and similarly $x^n=x$ for all $n\geq 1$. Therefore if $x^n=0$ for some $n$ then $x=0$.

For the second part, since $x^2=x$ it follows that $x(1-x)=0$. Therefore if $xy=1$ then multiplying by $1-x$ we get $1-x=0$, so $x=1$.

Comment: "multiplying by $1-x$" should be rather "multiplying by $x^{-1}$?

Comment: @rschwieb: No, $1-x$ is what I meant. $y$ is the inverse.

Comment: Oh, you were talking about $xy=1$. I was looking at $x(1-x)=0$. Never mind!